# Relationship between summation and convolution

Tags: summation, convolution, kronecker-delta

Currently I am reading a paper which derives a multiplication of matrix such as: $AB=I$, with $B$ is the inverse of $A$, $I$ is an identity matrix. This is the short hand notation for the following summation:
$$\sum_j a_{ij}b_{jk}=\delta_{ik}.$$
where $a_{ij}$ and $b_{jk}$ (which are functions of variable $h$) are elements of $A$ and $B$; $\delta_{ik}$ is Kronecker delta. The authors claim that the continuous equivalent of this summation is given by:
$$\{a*b\}(h)=\delta(h).$$
where * denotes the convolution. Actually, I cannot understand what theorem or properties behind this claim.
Is there anyone knows this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the equivalence is *not* when "$a_{ij}$ and $b_{jk}$ are functions of $h$".

In the equivalence to the continuous case, $h$ is taking over the roles of $i, j, k$. But it is easier to see when we use three continuous variables that correspond to each of the three indices, say $$i \to x, j \to y, k \to z$$
Then matrix elements correspond to
$$a_{ij} \to a(x - y)\\b_{jk} \to b(y - z)\\\delta_{ik} \to \delta(i - k)$$
and finally, the summation over $j$ becomes integration over $y$:

$$\int_{\Bbb R} a(x-y)b(y-z)dy = \delta(x - z)$$

Doesn't look quite right yet. So substitute $u = y - z$, then $du = dy$ and the limits don't change as $u$ still covers all of $\Bbb R$. but $x - y = x - z - u$, so it becomes
$$\int_{\Bbb R} a(x- z - u)b(u)du = \delta(x - z)$$
The expression on the left is the definition of $\{a*b\}(x - z)$. Substitute $h = x - z$ and you have your equivalence.

Comment: You may note that properly this continuous description is only equivalent to matrices that are constant along diagonals. The continuous analog of arbitrary matrices is different.

Comment: So is it possible to change from convolution (on the l.h.s of the last equation) to scalar multiplication by using Fourier transform, according to the convolution theorem? I mean can we receive $\hat{a}\hat{b}=1$, where $\hat$ is the Fourier transform?

Comment: And how can you map the indices of matrix to the continuous variables? Does this technique have a name? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm not mapping the indices of the matrix to continuous variables. It is just a correspondence in how things are used, that results from saying "hey, what happens if we use continuous variables instead of discrete ones for this purpose?" The best name I can give you for it is "an analogy". As for your other question, I haven't looked at Fourier transforms in a very, very long time, so I can't say.

Comment: Sorry but I spend days to look for any theory behind the correspondence of using continuous variables instead of discrete ones in the matrix product. It seems your derivation related to the Green function, which is regarded as matrices with continuous rows and columns. The unclear point to me is the term $a_{ij}\to a(x-y)$. It means $a$ is an entry of matrix $A$ with continuous indices $x,y$, but why $x-y$?

Furthermore, is the entry $a(x-y)$ now become a function of $x-y$ as seen in the convolution derivation?

Comment: There isn't some grand theory of "turning discrete indices into continuous variables". As I've already said, it is nothing more than recognizing analogous behavior in two cases. Convolutions were created and studied because they arose naturally while studying other things. Convolutions use $x -y$ because that is what was needed for what was being studied. My answer is *not* saying "this is the only way to do a continuous 'equivalent' of the discrete summation". There other "equivalences". I was only explaining how convolution is an equivalent.